# Hooking up a Business Layer and Repository using Unit of Work Pattern

Tags: architecture, business-logic, unit-of-work, repository-pattern

My question is similar to this one on Stack Overflow: [What is the correct way to use Unit of Work/Repositories within the business layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580651/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-unit-of-work-repositories-within-the-business-laye)

Scenario:

- .Net solution
- IRepository used to retrieve objects from DB
- IUnitOfWork used to allow transactions across multiple repositories

This makes sense to me and I have implemented something along these lines that works fine. Now I want to introduce a business logic layer and am having trouble organising the three elements (BLL, UnitOfWork and Repository) in my mind.

My understanding:

- Repository - data retrieval, manipulation
- UnitOfWork - persistence
- BLL - logic relevant to the business ('real world') (dislike that term!)

Consider we have an ASP.Net MVC front end.

What does a BLL look like and what does the MVC controller that uses it look like?

For reference:
I wonder if perhaps my IUnitOfWork/IRepository implementation might be the underlying cause of my confusion.

```cs
public class IRepository<T> 
{
    private IObjectSet<T> objSet;
    public IRepository<T>(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        objSet = uow.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Add(T entity)
    {
        objSet.Add(entity);
    }
    //etc. etc. for delete, attach, getall
}
```

So I feel like if I have a BLL, I should be passing it the IUnitOfWork, so that it can use that to create the IRepository instances that it needs. But how will the BLL (separate DLL from the front end) 'know' what implementation of IRepository to build?

Comment: I actually thought your question was just fine. The problem is, this is a fuzzy area; there's no One True Way™ to do it, and nobody wants to give you suggestions because they don't want to be told they're Doing It Wrong™. I personally prefer a thinner, more database table-centric approach on smaller projects; all of this ceremony is really intended for large-scale, enterprise applications.

Comment: Fair points both and the fault is then with my wording. I was interested in personal opinions i.e. 'this is how I personally would approach it'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Please note that I only have minor experience with the .NET framework and that this answer only relates to the architecture part of your question.*

As far as I understood it, you are basically applying the following architectural patterns in your application:

**Layers:** It seems you have a persistence layer (Repository Pattern), a business logic layer and a view layer.

**Model-View-Controller:** This pattern is applied in the view layer using ASP.NET MVC.

> I guess the question is: what does a BLL look like and what does the MVC controller that uses it look like?

First of all, this architecture is *intended for large-scale, enterprise applications* as Robert Harvey mentioned in his comment to your question. What is characteristic for such systems is that the domain logic (which you encapsulated in the business logic layer) should be accessible through various interfaces.

Consider Twitter for instance - Twitter could have a business logic layer which provides services for registering and validating users, posting tweets and much more. On top of this business logic layer, multiple other components could exist in the view layer, e.g. a web interface and web service component. Since all business logic is encapsulated in the business logic layer, you can follow the DRY principle and improve maintainability and other quality attributes.

To come back to your question - you should encapsulate business logic and data access in the BLL. The controller (think MVC) should make use of the BLL and should not have direct access to the database. Consider the view layer as an interface to your application.

> So I feel like if I have a BLL, I should be passing it the IUnitOfWork, so that it can use that to create the IRepository instances that it needs. But how will the BLL (separate DLL from the front end) 'know' what implementation of IRepository to build?

The BLL should know which repository (data source?) it uses. The layers above shouldn't control this. *Again, consider the view layer only as an interface to your business logic.*

If you don't need the overhead of a business logic layer, you may also choose to use it solely for data access in form of [data access objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

I hope this helped clarifying the various components' responsibilities.